# Java abstract class type mismatch

Tags: java

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class Car {
     private int carId;

     public Car(int carId) {
         this.carId = carId;
     }

     public int getCarId(c) {
       return carId;
     }

     public void setCarId(int carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
     }
}

public class Jeep extends Car {

   private String jeepModel;

   public Jeep(int carId) {
       super(carId);
   }

   public String getJeepModel() {
       return this.jeepModel;
   }

   public setJeepModel(String jeepModel) {
       this.jeepModel = jeepModel;
   }

}

public class AbstractClassExample {

   public Car car;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     car = new Jeep(1);
   }
}
```

When I do this I get the following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Jeep to Car

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't Car car be static ?

Comment: I don't see how you got that error you are saying. In fact there are other errors you should be getting.

Comment: Why would you set both the superclass and the current class their `carId` field to the same value? (and it won't compile since you have no field `id`)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I have updated the code. You are correct. I am still getting the error however.

Comment: Shouldn't be `public class Jeep extends Car {` or use abstract there too instead `public Jeep extends Car {`?

Comment: There are too many syntax errors here... fix those first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting **that exact error message**, but I find several other things which are strange in your code:

- When **Jeep** extends **Car** it does **not** need to re-declare the *carId* field
- In the **Jeep** constructor you're saying `this.id = carId` but you don't have a member field *id*
- **Car** doesn't have the *carId* constructor you're trying to use

Comment: +1. Nice, Kristiyane :)

Comment: Sorry, I hand typed everything out and made some errors. I fixed the car constructor to reflect my actual code.

Comment: @medium: It's generally really, really pointless to ask for help with syntax problems without showing your actual code - not something that "reflects" it. Instead of retyping it, copy it. And if that's too long, start deleting unimportant stuff while checking that your problem is still there. There's a good chance you'll find the error yourself when you do that, by the way.

Comment: @EelLee This _might_ be the answer or at least a step in the right direction to fixing that issue.

**Medium** - there are still quite a few errors in the code above other than the ones I've mentioned. Can you please paste the code entirely or link to a clipboard site where it is available? Having such small typo's or syntactic mistakes **often** leads to cryptic error messages like yours due to erroneous code parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It turned out that an import was colliding. I named an enum class Car and it was getting confused with the Car abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

you are use super(carId), which call the parent class constructor. In the abstract class car, u

not defined the constructor.Therefore, there is only default constructor is available[Car(){}]

solution

(1) create constructor in car class

```
car(int CarId)
{this.CarId=carId;}
```

(2)or call super()